# Multinomial mixed models with glmmADMB

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution

I want to run a multinomial mixed effects model with the glmmADMB package of R. I have read the available information of the programm but i couldn't find which family or link has to be used for multinomial data. In the examples are only shown models with Poisson, negative binomial and truncated binomial /poisson families.

Use of this package for multinomial mixed models has already been published (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378112715007288).

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Ana

Answer (score 3):

You can code a multinomial model as a variation on a binomial model and use the 'logit' link.

https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/

http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-multinomial-regression-models-in-r/

To handle multinomial models without recoding, you can use the [MCMCglmm](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MCMCglmm) package.