# Multinomial glmm with glmmADMB in R

Tags: r, mixed-model

I ran my multinomial model by using the R function glmmadmb. My response variable was a categorical variable with 4 levels. I extracted this summary from the model:

```
 Call:
 glmmadmb(formula = EEC_multinomial ~ call + duration + (1 | dyad),data = dur, family =  "binomial", link = "logit")

 AIC: 93.9 

 Coefficients:

                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)   11.222      2.148    5.23  1.7e-07 ***
    call1          8.576      3.910    2.19    0.028 *  
    duration      -0.129      0.113   -1.14    0.253    
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    Number of observations: total=207, diade=125 
    Random effect variance(s):
    Group=diade
            Variance StdDev
(Intercept)    232.1  15.23
Log-likelihood: -42.969
```

My question is: How can I see the effect of fixed factors on each level of my response?
Does the summary show the estimates related to the first level of my response?

Comment: When you say multinomial model what exactly are you trying to do? What is the nature of your variables and what question are you trying to answer?

Comment: if you are referring to the other factor in ```call``` it's the intercept

Comment: @StupidWolf I believe they are referring to the outcome variable `EEC_multinomial` which is categorical and has 4 levels.

Comment: mgcv package seems very slow and space inefficient. I was only able to estimate the binary model. The multinomial model could not complete the estimation.

Answer (score 9):

Anna, because you used *family = "binomial"* and *link = "logit"* as options in your model, R assumes that you are trying to model a *binary response variable* which takes the values 0 ("failure") or 1 ("success"). This assumption is also based on the fact that you didn't use cbind() on the left hand side of your model formula - otherwise, your response variable would have been treated as a *binomial count* (i.e., number of successes k out of n independent trials).

Under this assumption, what R is fitting is a *mixed effects binary logistic regression model*. This type of model looks at how the log odds of "success" are influenced by call and duration for a "typical" dyad and how the other dyads differ from the "typical" dyad with respect to the log odds of success corresponding to call1 = 0 and duration = 0.

On your left hand side of the model, you indicated through your response variable naming that your response is *multinomial*, which would mean that your response is NOT binary since it takes more than 2 values (i.e., at least 3). These values would be "categories" - for instance "failure", "success", "undetermined".  To fit a *mixed effects multinomial logistic regression model*, you would need to change your family from "binomial" to whatever the R package you are using suggests you should be using in a multinomial context.  I am not familiar with this package, so others here may be able to give you hints on what the appropriate family to use would be. It could be "multinomial" but you would have to check the package documentation to verify that.

**Addendum**

One possibility for fitting a mixed effects multinomial logistic regression model in a frequentist setting would be to use the function *npmlt* from the **mixcat** package of R.  Something like this:

```
install.packages("mixcat")
library(mixcat)

attach(dur)

model.po <- npmlt(formula = EEC_multinomial ~ call + duration, 
                  formula.npo = ~ 1, 
                  random = ~ 1|dyad, 
                  k = 2)

model.npo <- npmlt(formula = EEC_multinomial ~ call + duration, 
                  formula.npo = ~ 1 + call + duration, 
                  random = ~ 1|dyad, 
                  k = 2)

summary(model.po)

summary(model.npo)

detach(dur)
```

Note that you need to make sure your outcome variable, EEC_multinomial, is treated as a factor by R.  Also, you need to attach your dataset prior to fitting your model(s) and then detach it after fitting your model(s).

If EEC_multinomial has 3 categories, say, R will set one category aside and treat it as the baseline (or reference) category.  If the 3 categories are A, B and C and A is the reference category, the *npmlt* function will model two sets of log odds:

1. Log odds of response variable falling in category B rather than A as a function of (i) your predictor variables and (ii) a random intercept for Subject;
2. Log odds of response variable falling in category C rather than A as a function of (i) your predictor variables and (ii) a random intercept for Subject;

How *npmlt* will model these log odds will depend on your specification of the model:

- For model.po, *npmlt* will assume that the effect of the predictor variable *call* is same for both sets of log odds, conditional on the random intercept effect AND that the effect of the predictor variable *duration* is the same for both sets of log odds. [This is called the *proportional odds* assumption or *po* in short.]
- For model.npo, *npmlt* will assume that the effect of each of the predictor variables *call* and *duration* is different across the two sets of log odds, conditional on the random intercept effect.  [This is called the "nonproportional odds assumption" or *npo* in short.]

Of course, you could also formulate models where one of the predictors satisfies the po assumption and the other does not and viceversa:

```
model.npo.1 <- npmlt(formula = EEC_multinomial ~ call + duration, 
                      formula.npo = ~ 1 + call, 
                      random = ~ 1|dyad, 
                      k = 2)

model.npo.2 <- npmlt(formula = EEC_multinomial ~ call + duration, 
                      formula.npo = ~ 1 + duration, 
                      random = ~ 1|dyad, 
                      k = 2)
```

The predictor variables listed in both *formula* and *formula.npo* do NOT satisfy the proportional odds assumption.  The predictor variables listed only in *formula* DO satisfy the proportional odds assumption.

I have not used this function much so please check out how you can best set the value of k in your model (e.g., contact the package author for guidance on choice of k or try out different k > 1 values to make sure your end results and conclusions are not sensitive to the choice of k).

There are other R packages for fitting this type of models, some of which will take you to a Bayesian (e.g., **brms**) rather than frequentist framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did a binomial model with this package since I followed this answer on this blog: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204426/multinomial-mixed-models-with-glmmadmb. I'll try with another package in R since the documentation does not specify which family I should choose for a multinomial model.

Comment: Anna, please see my Addendum for one possible R package you could use.

Comment: (+1) very nice Isabella - I had been thinking about this question earlier today but couldn't come up with a satisfactory answer :)

Comment: Thank you, Robert! I spent some time yesterday trying to find a nice R package that fits this type of model in a frequentist setting and ended up going down a rabbit hole.  It’s not easy to find a package that has nice documentation as well as flexibility regarding the proportional odds assumption.  The **mixcat** package offers the flexibility but could have better documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much @Isabella You're right, it is not easy to find a package for this kind of models, but this one seems to be very useful!

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to the party here but I really struggled to find a good way to do a mixed multinomial regression and didn't have success with the mixcat package, mostly due to the near complete lack of support/documentation. Just thought I'd add a different solution for anyone else struggling with this - you can use the gam() function of the mgcv package, and set family=multinom(). This package has much better support and flexibility than the other alternatives that I've found.

So to run the model in the example, you would use

```
 mgcv::gam(list(EEC_multinomial ~ call + duration + s(dyad, bs="re"),
                                ~ call + duration + s(dyad, bs="re"),
                                ~ call + duration + s(dyad, bs="re")),
            data = dur, family = multinom(K=3))
```

where EEC_multinomial is an integer with the reference level equal to 0 and the categorical variables are factors.

The `s(dyad, bs="re")` is the random effect term for dyad, and the K value specified in multinom is the number of levels of the categorical response minus 1. Because there are four levels to this response, K=3 and we must repeat the formula three times, within a list. The summary() output of the model will show three sections - the summary for each level of the response compared to the reference level. This also allows the flexibility to include different predictors for different levels of the response.