A doubt for a multinomial mixed effect model
Suppose I had 243 individuals take a questionnaire. The questionnaire contains 100 questions referring to certain verbs, and the individual, for each verb, has to guess the noun or adjective that is root of that verb. I then have a dataset with the response variable y that relates to whether the individual answered correctly, got it wrong, or preferred not to answer (thus a three-level factor), a unique identifier ID of the individual, and an identifier of the verb ITEM, along with a number of other explanatory variables x1, x2,... which have to do with the rarity of the verb and whether the root of the verb was a noun or an adjective.
I suppose I could model the response variable y through a multinomial mixed model, in which y varies as a function of the fixed effects x1, x2, ..., and in which the random effects are given by the individual and the verb. What would be the correct specification of random effects (for example ~ (1|ID) + (1|ITEM) or something else)? Which R package should I use?

Are you sure your response variable is multinomial, or is it perhaps ordinal? That is, an incorrect answer might be worse performance than not answered. In that case, you need a mixed model for ordinal data, see R package GLMMadaptive by
Dimitris Rizopoulos, here is the package vignette (tutorial): https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Ordinal_Mixed_Models.html
Indeed, it seems appropriate to include a random effect for person and item with (1|ID) + (1|ITEM). But in GLMMadaptive you'll need nlme-style (not of lme4-style) specification:
random = list(ID = 1, ITEM = 1)
If you do consider the response categorical, not ordered categorical, using function gam from package mgcv would be an option. You specify a random intercept such as (1|ID) as s(ID, bs = "re"). See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/555654/173546

The response has levels "correct", "wrong", "Preferred not to answer", so I don't think it's ordinal.

I found mclogit package and its function mblogit. What do you think of it?
