# Is there a mixed effects regression model with categorical but non-binomial response variable? (i.e. more than 2 outcomes?)

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I have a set of data which does not fit the typical parameters for parametric tests of association, and I need to account for the one of the variables as a random effect.

After research, I found that a mixed effects model [(as described here)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-46216-1_22) is the best fit for my data.

So I've been using the glmer function in the lme4 package for R as such:

```
glmm.01 <- glmer(type ~ 1 + pros_length + initial_i + false_start + pause + gaze_shift + rapid_blink + gest_dis + (1 | speaker), data = df, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

It works quite well if the response variable `type` contains only two possible outcomes, let's call them Type A and Type B. However, I have reasons to subset some of the Type B observations into its own category, Type C.

I run the model again, and it works, but I can't tell which categories the predictors are predictive of.

So two questions:

1. Is there some kind of post-hoc I can run to figure out the conditionality of these predictors?
2. Is this even the correct test for a trinominal regression? I know that the `family` argument is set to `binomial`. But as far as I can tell from the glmer documentation, there doesn't seem to another value I can put there that corresponds to having a trinomial response variable.

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Can these categories be ordered?

Comment: I don't think so. To provide more detail, I'm looking at a certain word root, which can manifest as three different word classes: noun vs. verb. discourse marker. They can't be ranked.

Comment: If the categorical outcomes are mutually exclusive and can't be ordered, then you can use [multinomial regression](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/). There are [over 100 pages on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multinomial+mixed+model) dealing with aspects of multinomial mixed models. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/204426/28500) has links to building mixed models with multinomial outcomes. Please look those over, and edit this question to specify any particular outstanding issues that remain.